# When several C static libs contain methods with same signature, this induces linker ambiguous behaviour

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, linker, static-libraries, ambiguity

My environment:
 Win embedded (WES2009) RealTime driver, API written in C in  MSVS2008 / VS2010. Result: 2 independend libs, implementing 2 independent solutions: 2 APIs of 2 serial port drivers.

A simple problem: 
 I have these 2 static libs, corresponding to 2 different serial port drivers. Both of them are used in another VS2008 project, where I call API of serial port driver(s). The signature of functions are same in both libs, but their implementation differs.

My simple question is:
 What are the rules for the VS2008 linker ? Which lib will it link, as it did not cast linker error of multiple function definition ?

---

I've scanned through similar Q/A's but none seem to address this particular problem. They usually deal with equal_named.lib:

[How linker solves ambiguities when linking *.libs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043062/how-linker-solves-ambiguities-when-linking-libs)

or this one addresses same question but with unix GCC linker:

[Linking in several C object files that contain functions with equivalent signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431057/linking-in-several-c-object-files-that-contain-functions-with-equivalent-signatu)

Thank you for enlightment :)

Comment: When you say "same signature", you don't mean only argument and return types, but the same *name* as well?

Comment: @Joachim: Thanx for reply. Certainly. I think that is the definition of signature. Same name + arg list and order. Moreover, the ret. value is same too.
Briefly: signatures + ret. Vals are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, that when I add a .lib to my project, MSVS2008+ pops up a window asking me if I want to create a linking rule for the new library. I'd say this is the only possibility in some cases. When you #include headers from both libraries (or if both libs contain same named header), the linker has no chance to distinguish which one you meant.
Im my case, the behavior of linker became undeterminable, without a linking rule.

But the best praxis is to avoid such situations. I'd rather use only one library, or refactor names in one of them.